# Elegant way to iterate into a multilevel pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, multi-index

I have a DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,6)) cols = [['A', 'B', 'C'],
['AA','BB']] a.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    cols,
    names= ['first lvl', 'second level'])
```

which gives a MultiIndex df as per below:

```
first lvl            A                   B                   C          
second level        AA        BB        AA        BB        AA        BB
0             0.991608  0.469706  0.338347  0.254777  0.739046  0.980094
1             0.039133  0.959985  0.718216  0.746632  0.341260  0.264836
2             0.164068  0.158672  0.175882  0.211732  0.146807  0.678957
3             0.324433  0.343780  0.269040  0.432309  0.469457  0.247455
4             0.932380  0.314262  0.439924  0.037954  0.641936  0.011523
5             0.608288  0.308212  0.680107  0.988747  0.349255  0.775298
6             0.082478  0.859175  0.546415  0.471169  0.013312  0.824054
7             0.244569  0.049261  0.194941  0.350334  0.203621  0.408066
8             0.132751  0.092825  0.237527  0.383277  0.288257  0.764209
9             0.417155  0.578300  0.325731  0.504903  0.718891  0.861813
```

I would like for iterate through columns A, B and C and do a `np.polyfit(AA, BB, deg=1)`.

Is there an elegant and simple way to do other than with:

```
cols = np.unique(a.columns.get_level_values(0)) beta =
[np.polyfit(a[col]['AA'], a[col]['BB'], deg= 1) for col in cols]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
beta = [np.polyfit(a[col]['AA'], a[col]['BB'], deg= 1) for col in a.stack().columns]
```

It does what you want in one line

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` in columns and apply custom funstion `f`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,6)) 
cols = [['A', 'B', 'C'],['AA','BB']]
a.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( cols, names= ['first lvl', 'second level'])
print (a)
irst lvl            A                   B                   C          
second level        AA        BB        AA        BB        AA        BB
0             0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776  0.004719  0.121569
1             0.670749  0.825853  0.136707  0.575093  0.891322  0.209202
2             0.185328  0.108377  0.219697  0.978624  0.811683  0.171941
3             0.816225  0.274074  0.431704  0.940030  0.817649  0.336112
4             0.175410  0.372832  0.005689  0.252426  0.795663  0.015255
5             0.598843  0.603805  0.105148  0.381943  0.036476  0.890412
6             0.980921  0.059942  0.890546  0.576901  0.742480  0.630184
7             0.581842  0.020439  0.210027  0.544685  0.769115  0.250695
8             0.285896  0.852395  0.975006  0.884853  0.359508  0.598859
9             0.354796  0.340190  0.178081  0.237694  0.044862  0.505431

print (a.groupby(level=0, axis=1)
        .apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(x[(x.name, 'AA')],
                                    x[(x.name, 'BB')], deg= 1)))
A    [-0.200103361495, 0.477549562164]
B     [0.415374076332, 0.473118297463]
C     [-0.33785161273, 0.551131295356]
dtype: object
```